# Export Manipulate output into .pdf (or as link into .pdf)

Tags: manipulate, export

Is there a process of embedding Manipulate output into .pdf document, or alternatively creating a link of the Manipulate output, which can be added into .pdf.

For example, I would like to add the output of

```
Manipulate[Plot[Sin[n x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}], {n, 1, 20}]
```

into lecture notes to demonstrate effect of varying parameter for angular frequency.

Kind regards, Richard

Comment: Embedding it directly into the PDF will not be possible. For creating a link to an interactive version, see [`CloudPublish`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CloudPublish.html) (note that published stuff may not remain accessible forever depending on your account type)

Comment: Thank you, Lukas, for prompt reply.  I will investigate the idea and see if I can manage to get this concept working.

Comment: You can embed Mathematica video into a PDF file using the animate package which has it's own animation controls.  If you're interested how let me know and I'll post an example.

Comment: Dear Josh, I am very interested to see your example. Kind regards, R

Comment: @Josh I would be very much interested! Tahnks

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, didn't see the first request for an example and just saw aprendiz request also.  Here it is:

First create frames of the video in Mathematica and save as png type:

```
 SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
videoFrameData = Table[Plot[Sin[a + x], {x, 0, 10}], {a, 20}];
Export["d:\\NewFunctionFolder2\\pdfVideoTestFile.png", videoFrameData,
   "VideoFrames"];
```

Now create the latex code with the `animate` package shown below.  I use TeXnic Center and included the `lstlisting` package to include a listing of the  Mathematica code in the PDF file for reference.  Now compile it into a PDF file and run it.  It will show a frame of the video and a Manipulate-like GUI for running the animation.

```
    \documentclass[12pt,reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage{animate}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\lstdefinestyle{myMathematica}{
frame=tb,
  language=Mathematica,
  aboveskip=3mm,
  belowskip=3mm,
  showstringspaces=false,
  columns=flexible,
  basicstyle={\ttfamily},
  numbers=none,
  numberstyle=\tiny\color{gray},
  keywordstyle=\color{blue},
  commentstyle=\color{mauve},
  stringstyle=\color{dkgreen},
  breaklines=true,
  breakatwhitespace=true,
    morekeywords={AsymptoticSolve},
  tabsize=3
 }

\definecolor{dkgreen}{rgb}{0,0.6,0}
\definecolor{gray}{rgb}{0.5,0.5,0.5}
\definecolor{mauve}{rgb}{0.58,0,0.82}




\begin{document}

This is a test of imbeding Mathematica video into PDF file using animate package.  First create the video frames and save in directory of this TeXnicCenter latex file:

    \begin{center}
    \begin{minipage}{0.85\linewidth}
    \begin{lstlisting}[title={Mathematica Code},style=myMathematica,
    frame=single,
    label=code2]
    SetDirectory[NotebookDirectory[]];
    videoFrameData = Table[Plot[Sin[a + x], {x, 0, 10}], {a, 20}];
    Export["d:\\NewFunctionFolder2\\pdfVideoTestFile.png", videoFrameData, "VideoFrames"];
    
        \end{lstlisting}
        \end{minipage}
        \end{center}
    
    
    \begin{center}
    \animategraphics[controls,loop,width=3in]{3}{pdfVideoTestFile}{1}{20}
    \end{center}
    
    
    
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Your Mathematica code and LaTeX frame ranges differ (both  file names and  number of frames). This might confuse copy/paste users.

Comment: @Acus:  Ok thanks.  I updated the code and also better defined both the video data and video data file names to make more clear.

Comment: Thank you very much